# Array to CSV, not the right format

Tags: powershell, csv

I used the ">" operator to put the content of an array into a CSV file, here is what i got, the first line is empty

```
Computer                                                    IP                                                         
--------                                                    --                                                         
IMPPRD1                                                     172.22.30.33                                               
IMPPRD2                                                     172.22.30.31                                               
IMPPRD3                                                     172.22.30.32                                               
IMPSR1                                                      172.22.30.12                                               
IMPPRD5                                                     172.22.30.17
```

I would like it to be a normal CSV, so something like this :

```
Computer,IP                                                                                                        
IMPPRD1,172.22.30.33                                               
IMPPRD2,172.22.30.31                                               
IMPPRD3,172.22.30.32                                               
IMPSR1,172.22.30.12
```

How could I manage to do this using powershell? 
Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried `$array | Export-Csv filename` ?

Comment: Yeaaaah, I already tried it but I didn't think of putting the pipe, haha, nice, thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

Using `>` outputs as normal text - including the spaces between columns. Basically the same as `Write-Output`. You are looking for `Export-Csv` which outputs in CSV format.